# Same modal popup is to be called for different button clicks with slightly different data in the modal popup for each call

Tags: angular, typescript, modal-dialog

Being new to Angular 4 I came across with an issue.
In my code currently I have 2 separate components for 2 different modals in my code for 2 different button clicks (Add User and Edit User).
Now I have a requirement where I have to come up with a single modal popup that fires in both the cases (i.e. on click of 'Add User' as well as 'Edit User').
All the fields in both the modals are same except that the Edit User modal is already populated with user data while Add User modal shows empty fields.
Any help regarding this is highly appreciated. :)

Comment: Just show the code how you handle to call the modals

Comment: Hi Rahul Swamynathan, you can refer the code that sasensi provided below just as an example and please go through my comment there too for the issue that I got following the solution he provided.
Any help in this is highly appreciated.

Comment: Use `ngx-bootstrap` where you will find a solution - sorry i don't have idea about `matdialog` - check this link [https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals] - if you are using `ngx-bootstrap` i will provide you some solution - Thanks

Comment: Thanku Rahul Swamynathan. I'll this approach :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [simple stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sasensi-dialog-example) using [Angular Material Dialog Component](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview) to display a different modal depending on which button was clicked.
The main principle consists in passing data to your modal and adapt its content to what was passed.
In this example, I simply pass a string: `add` or `edit`.

#### main component

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { DialogComponent } from './dialog.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
    <button (click)="openDialog('add')">add</button>
    <button (click)="openDialog('edit')">edit</button>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) { }

    openDialog(action) {
        this.dialog.open(DialogComponent, {
            data: action
        });
    }
}
```

#### modal component

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';

@Component({
    template: `
    <h4>action = {{action}}</h4>
    <p *ngIf="action === 'add'">add content displayed</p>
    <p *ngIf="action === 'edit'">edit content displayed</p>
  `,
})
export class DialogComponent {
    constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public action: string) { }
}
```

Comment: Hi Sasensi, thankyou so much for your response. I tried your solution but I faced another problem. The thing is my project is in Angular version 4 but for Angular 'material' and 'cdk' there is no version in 4.x. It directly goes from 2.x beta versions to 5.x.
I can't change my project's angular core version from 4.x to any other due to certain project constraints. So is there any way around to this for the same task ? I would highly appreciate any help in this.

Comment: It seems that Material 2.x beta can be used with Angular 4 (see this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2)). Unfortunately, Material 2.x documentation is no longer online so you'll have to build it yourself (see this [discussion](https://github.com/angular/material.angular.io/issues/332)) in order to adapt the code I provided.

Comment: Thankyou so much Sasensi, I'll go through the solution that you provided. Thanks for your time, I highly appreciate it :)